# Custom field in a shortcode?

Tags: custom-field, customization, shortcode

I cannot get the image from one of my fields into a shortcode.
(it works with `get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'thumbnail')` but I need the value from the field `udstiller logo`.

```
function logo_shortcode( $atts ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'limit' => '50',
        'orderby' => 'name',
    ), $atts ) );
    // Creating custom query to fetch the project type custom post.
    $loop = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'udstillere', 'posts_per_page' => $limit, 'orderby' => $orderby));
    $output = '<ul class="bxslider">';
    // Looping through the posts and building the HTML structure.
    if($loop){
        while ($loop->have_posts()){
             $loop->the_post();
             $output .= '<li><a href="'.get_permalink().'"><img src="'.get_post_meta($post->ID,'wpcf-udstiller-logo',true).'"/></a></li>';

        }
    }
    else
        $output = 'Sorry, No projects yet. Come back Soon.';
    // Now we are returning the HTML code back to the place from where the shortcode was called.
    return $output;
    $output = '</ul>';
}
add_shortcode("Logo", "logo_shortcode");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$post` is global variable, so it's not visible in this scope (and when you use `$post` in your code, you're not referring to global `$post` variable but to local one)

You should put `global $post` somewhere in your code. For example like this:

```
...
while ($loop->have_posts()){
    global $post;
    $loop->the_post();
    $output .= '<li><a href="'.get_permalink().'"><img src="'.get_post_meta($post->ID,'wpcf-udstiller-logo',true).'"/></a></li>';
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Whilst @Krzysiek Dróżdż's answer is fine, I would recommend simply using `get_the_ID()` instead of `$post->ID`.